# Mysql Group by time interval optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, indexing

I have a very large table (several hundred millions of rows) that stores test results along with a datetime and a foreign key to a related entity called 'link', I need to to group rows by time intervals of 10,15,20,30 and 60 minutes as well as filter by time and 'link_id' I know this can be done with this query as explained [here][1]:

```
SELECT time,AVG(RTT),MIN(RTT),MAX(RTT),COUNT(*) FROM  trace
WHERE link_id=1 AND time>='2015-01-01' AND time <= '2015-01-30'
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 600;
```

This solution worked but it was extremely slow (about 10 on average) so I tried adding a datetime column for each 'group by interval' for example the row:

```
id | time                     | rtt        | link_id
1  | 2014-01-01 12:34:55.4034 | 154.3      | 2
```

became:

```
id | time                     | rtt        | link_id | time_60                   |time_30 ...
1  | 2014-01-01 12:34:55.4034 | 154.3      | 2       | 2014-01-01 12:00:00.00    | 2014-01-01 12:30:00.00 ...
```

and I get the intervals with the following query:

```
SELECT time_10,AVG(RTT),MIN(RTT),MAX(RTT),COUNT(*) FROM  trace
WHERE link_id=1 AND time>='2015-01-01' AND time <= '2015-01-30'
GROUP BY time_10;
```

this query was at least 50% faster (about 5 seconds on average) but it is still pretty slow, how can I optimize this query to be faster?

explain query outputs this:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                                                          | key                                                | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main_trace | ref  | main_trace_link_id_c6febb11f84677f_fk_main_link_id,main_trace_e7549e3e | main_trace_link_id_c6febb11f84677f_fk_main_link_id | 4       | const | 1478359 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

and these are the table indexes:

```
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| main_trace |          0 | PRIMARY                                            |            1 | id          | A         |     2956718 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_link_id_c6febb11f84677f_fk_main_link_id |            1 | link_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_07cc694b                                |            1 | time        | A         |     2956718 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_e7549e3e                                |            1 | time_10     | A         |       22230 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_01af8333                                |            1 | time_15     | A         |       14783 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_1681ff94                                |            1 | time_20     | A         |       10870 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_f7c28c93                                |            1 | time_30     | A         |        6399 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| main_trace |          1 | main_trace_0f29fcc5                                |            1 | time_60     | A         |        3390 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT time_10, AVG(RTT), MIN(RTT), MAX(RTT), COUNT(*)
FROM  trace
WHERE link_id = 1 AND time >= '2015-01-01' AND time <= '2015-01-30'
GROUP BY time_10;
```

The best index is the covering index: `trace(link_id, time, time_10, rtt)`.

Comment: why would you include rtt in that index?
also... should I make an index like this for each
time_x column? I have time_10, time_15, time_20, time_30 and time_60

Comment: @JesusGomez . . .  That makes it a covering index for the query.  The entire query can use the index.  There may be no need to go to the data pages.  And, for performance, yes.  However, I would  try running the original query with an index on `trace(link_id, time, rtt)`.  Maybe you don't need the extra columns.

Comment: Tried both aproaches, first I added a trace(link_id, time, rtt) and tried both queries, without any performance improvement, then I added the covering index trace(link_id, time, time_10, rtt) and the query completed in only 2 seconds. I'm a bit concerned about the insertion times having so many indexes in a single table.

Comment: @JesusGomez . . . The number of columns in an index has (very, very little) impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

a composite index on (id,time) followed by a potential `analyze table trace` would make it snappy.

It is just a suggestion, I am not saying to do it. Analyze table can take some people hours to run with millions of rows.

Suggesting index creation based on just one query is not a great idea. Assumption being, you have other queries. And they are a drag on inserts/updates.

Comment: The insertion time is important because insertions will be constantly happening in this table, other queries are either very similar or just select and filter by time.

Comment: covering indexes are awesome. no need for data page lookups. You will need to do the balancing act of what is right for your system :>  covering, composite, or as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

`time <= '2015-01-30'` excludes most of the last day of January; did you want that?  This pattern works well, and avoids many endcases (eg, leapyear):

```
WHERE time >= '2015-01-01'
  AND time  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If this is static data (such as a write-once Data Warehouse), you could make the query *much* faster by building and maintaining [Summary Tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Comment: great catch! thank you very much, this is indeed write-once data Summary   Tables seem like a great solution if my current solution doesn't scale further.